# YCM support for standard python libraries

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin, youcompleteme

I am setting my Vim environment for python developing, so far managed to install YCM and tired it.

It works fine with classes , built in methods for variables etc ..

But can I get the methods for libraries for example :

```
from time import localtime
time_now = localtime()
hour = time_now. ==> I need to see the list of of options here
```

Anyone has done this setting before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing [jedi-vim](https://travis-ci.org/davidhalter/jedi-vim) with [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) instead of YCM fixes this problem